# Apply Pattern#astMatchPredicate with Stream#takeWhile

Tags: java, stream, predicate

I try to apply a Predicte from a Pattern to a Stream of Strings:

```
final var someString = "first\nsecond\nthird"
final var myPattern  = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("second");
final var sb         = new java.lang.StringBuilder();

someString.lines()
  .takeWhile(not(myPattern::asMatchPredicate))
  .forEachOrdered(sb::append)
  ;
```

But the compiler refuses this with the error:

```
 method asMatchPredicate in class java.util.regex.Pattern cannot be applied to given types
  required: no arguments
  found: java.lang.String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

But why? The predicate takes a string (`Predicate<String>`) and the `takeWhile` method expects a `Predicate<? extends String>`.

Comment: Try `.takeWhile(not(myPattern.asMatchPredicate()))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effectively you're doing the following:

```java
Predicate<String> predicate = myMatcher::asMatchPredicate;
```

The method reference means you're trying to implement your own `Predicate<String>` instead of using the one returned by `Pattern#asMatchPredicate()`. That cannot work in this case for two reasons:

1. The `Pattern#asMatchPredicate()` method accepts no arguments, but the `Predicate#test(T)` method accepts a single argument.
2. The `Pattern#asMatchPredicate()` method returns a `Predicate<String>`, but the `Predicate#test(T)` method returns a `boolean`.

Since the `Pattern#asMatchPredicate()` method already returns a `Predicate<String>` there's no reason to use a method reference here—just negate the returned value. In other words, you could do either:

```java
.takeWhile(Predicate.not(myMatcher.asMatchPredicate()))
```

Or:

```java
.takeWhile(myMatcher.asMatchPredicate().negate())
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing it can be by negating the regex pattern i.e. use `^((?!second).)*$` as the regex pattern.

**Demo:**

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final var someString = "first\nsecond\nthird";
        final var myPattern = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("^((?!second).)*$");
        final var sb = new java.lang.StringBuilder();

        someString.lines().takeWhile(myPattern.asPredicate()).forEachOrdered(sb::append);
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
first
```

**Explanation of the regex as [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/0YCFvz/1):**

[image]

Comment: The result is `firstsecondthird`.